# ImportError: cannot import name FileModeWarning

Tags: python, swift, openstack-swift, keystone

I have set up an all in one swift. While setting up keystone in all-in-one-swift I am having an error when I try to create the service entity and API endpoints. I followed liberty documentation but couldn't resolve this issue!
[Documentation link](http://docs.openstack.org/liberty/install-guide-rdo/keystone-services.html)

```
 [root@arupsaio ~]# openstack service create --name keystone --description "OpenStack Identity" identity
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/openstack", line 6, in <module>
    from openstackclient.shell import main
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openstackclient/shell.py", line 30, in <module>
    from openstackclient.common import clientmanager
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openstackclient/common/clientmanager.py", line 23, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/utils.py", line 32, in <module>
    from .exceptions import InvalidURL, FileModeWarning
ImportError: cannot import name FileModeWarning
```

Comment: `pip install --upgrade requests` might help, since earlier versions of requests module do not have exception class *FileModeWarning*

Comment: thank you, but i didn't work, it's already up to date.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, there were some package leftovers.
I had to uninstall the package 3 times!

```
pip uninstall requests # x3
```

And then reinstall the new version

```
pip install requests
```